# CSS: allow textarea to grow with contents up to a limit

Tags: css

On certain sites (eg Github), the textareas have a set `min-height` and `max-height`.  As the user types into them, they grow with content until they reach their max height. Then vertical scroll bars appear.

How is this effect accomplished?  My textarea does not grow with its contents even though it hasn't reached the specified `max-height`

```
textarea{
  width:100%;
  min-height:80px;
  max-height:200px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

[Look at this demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqMjaP)

Comment: jQuery's `.autoResize()` is probably doing the trick, that or `<div contentedible='true'>`

Comment: _"How is this effect accomplished?"_ With JavaScript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out this [Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLdRXE).

> JS

This snippet do the trick:

```
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

textarea.addEventListener('keydown', autosize);

function autosize(){
  var el = this;
  setTimeout(function(){
    el.style.cssText = 'height:auto; padding:0';
    // for box-sizing other than "content-box" use:
    // el.style.cssText = '-moz-box-sizing:content-box';
    el.style.cssText = 'height:' + el.scrollHeight + 'px';
  },0);
}
```

> CSS

And i added this to the css to make it only resizable vertically:

```
  resize:vertical;
```

Comment: Thank you Sid. Why are you editing the size in a different thread? (using `setTimeout`).  Is there any functional reason you set `padding:0` or is it just a matter of preference?

Comment: Is just a matter of preference, to be sure not to have any cross-browser issues. You might as well delete it.

Comment: ok. What about my first question: why use `setTimeout`? When your `autosize()` is called, the `keydown` event has just registered. Why fork into another thread?

Comment: It used to be there for making it a bit more fluid. By the way i used this like a long time ago so i think it's obsolete, i just checked and found [this](http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/frudD) that might help you.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I like your solution better because it doesn't rely on a 3rd party library (no jQuery in my project)

Answer (score 5):

Native HTML/CSS involves faking a textarea with `contenteditable`. But a JavaScript/jQuery solution would probably more suitable, however: for documentation purposes:

```css
.container{width:300px; border:1px solid blue; padding:10px}
.textarea{
  width:100%;
  min-height:80px;
  max-height:200px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='textarea' contenteditable='true'>Hello world</div>
</div>
```

Automatically resizes when the user is entering more content due to the nature of behaving `<div>` elements.

Comment: oh wow that's really clever. Didn't even know about the `contenteditable` attribute, though [it has great support](http://caniuse.com/contenteditable)