# TextArea dont auto-resize correct when starting on one row

Tags: html, css

I having some trouble to get a textarea to auto expand from one row.
It works when I have 3 or more rows and one row, but the two first looks weird.

Can't find a good way of knowing when the text is clipped like that. Because the lenght of the input will be dynamic.
I have seen solutions that kind of work here on Stackoverflow, but I must have the total height of the input to start at 40px; And the solutions I have seen cant handle that case.

[image]

(Dont mind the black-border for the textarea, for some reason codeSandBox shows it but not for me.)

I have a codeSandbox that shows the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-yalow-fnqnep?file=/src/App.js:241-296

Anyone had a similliar issue or could point me in the right direction?

Edit:
Working React component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const InputWrapper = styled.div`
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
`;

const StyledTextArea = styled.textarea`
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  line-height: 18px;
  resize: none;
  transition: all 300ms;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
`;
const TextArea = ({ value, placeholder, handleEvent }) => {
  const [textAreaRef, setTextAreaRef] = useState(React.createRef());
  const updateHeight = () => {
    const updatedTextArea = { ...textAreaRef };
    updatedTextArea.current.style.height = "";
    updatedTextArea.current.style.height = `${updatedTextArea.current.scrollHeight}px`;
    setTextAreaRef(updatedTextArea);
  };

  useEffect(() => updateHeight(), [value]);

  return (
    <InputWrapper>
      <StyledTextArea
        ref={textAreaRef}
        value={value}
        rows={1}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onChange={handleEvent}
      />
    </InputWrapper>
  );
};

export default TextArea;
```

Comment: Please add you code to the question body as text / stack snippet and not in an external site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: allow textarea to grow with contents up to a limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41099097/css-allow-textarea-to-grow-with-contents-up-to-a-limit) (Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41099294/1650337), you just need to remove the max height)

Comment: ATP: Whats wrong with a codeSandbox link? Then people can edit and maybe understand better. @DBS That post don't solve the issue to start one row unfortunately :/.

Comment: SO aims to build up a repository of questions and answers for future readers. External sites disappear. SO has its own snippet system which allows editing.

Comment: Aahh thx @AHaworth makes sense, sorry for being stupid :P

Comment: rows={1} did the trick. Sorry only having the codeSandBox.
Will post the working code in my post.